# Laravel Query Builder - Convert MySQL quert to Laravel Query Builder

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5, query-builder

I have a query in MySQL:

```
SELECT student, ((SUM(mark1)+SUM(mark2))/SUM(mark3)) AS avg FROM your_table
```

and

```
SELECT student, (mark1+mark2-mark3) AS result FROM your_table
```

I like to convert them to Laravel's query builder format query.

But I can't find any way to do that.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I like to avoid DB:raw. Is there any way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something like this

```
Student::select( DB::raw('student, ((SUM(mark1)+SUM(mark2))/SUM(mark3)) AS avg ')->get();
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I like to avoid DB:raw. Is there any way?

Comment: Querybuilder is trying to help you write SQL... it's a helper.  So all of the php you write is eventually going to be converted to SQL anyways.  Not all cases will fit into it though so you have to use DB::raw() for advanced use cases.  This isn't a bad thing so don't sell yourself on the fact that it is.  Raw SQL is 10x faster than php anyways.

Comment: Yes, but BD:RAW has a security hole, so everyone should try to avoid that.

Comment: Only if your passing it unsanitized data which you shouldn't be doing.

Comment: Thanks for let me know

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for helping, but I have found the solution-

```
 $baseQuery =   DB::table('employee')->select('employee_name', DB::raw('employee_salary/employee_extension as employee_salary'), 'employee_position', 'employee_city', 'employee_extension',"employee_joining_date", 'employee_age', 'employee_id');
```

Should be in this format